# How to show a notice after submitting a simple form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, simple-form

I'm using Simple Form and Ajax and I want to show a notice(it can be flash) something like "Successfully Submitted", after successful submission of a form. How can I achieve this?

This my controller:

```
def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id

  end
```

and my form in views:

```
<%= form_for OrderItem.new,  html: {class: "add-to-cart"}, remote: true do |f| %>


        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :quantity, value: 1, min: 1 %>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
            <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "btn btn-default black-background white" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734020/how-to-display-messages-aka-flash-without-rendering-or-redirecting

Answer (score 1):

You can do it responding to a javascript request when form is submitted.

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/mycontroller.rb

def create
  @order = current_order
  @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
  @order.user_id = current_user.id
  @order.save
  session[:order_id] = @order.id

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "Created order" } 
  end
end
```

And then create a view to show the message:

```
# app/mycontroller/create.js.erb

<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  $('.add-to-cart').append('<%= j content_tag :div, value, class: "flash #{key}" %>')
<% end %>
```

It should work!

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap alert to achieve it.
Controller:

```
    def create
      @order = current_order
      @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
      @order.user_id = current_user.id

      if @order.save
         flash[:success] = "Successfully Submitted"
      end

      session[:order_id] = @order.id
    end
```

You can display that flash message wherever you want to using this

View:

```
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
       <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
```